# Multiprocessing python. Error ''dict' object is not callable'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess run method in my class. The method returns a dictionary. I do not understand why I am getting the error "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable". I have seen threads saying instance methods can not be pickled and need to be pickled/unpickled manually. However, I am not getting that error here and I wonder why. I just want to multiprocess one of my instance methods and use the result in another instance method. Attached is the minimum working example.

```
            #/usr/bin/python
            from multiprocessing import Pool

            class test:

                def __init__(self):
                    print "init"

                def  run(self):
                    y = {'write_bandwidth': 3768.3135113756257}
                    return y

                def pool(self):
                    pool = Pool(processes=2)              
                    result = pool.map(self.run(), range(10)) 
                    print result

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                t = test();
                t.pool()
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
            init
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/preetigupta25/Documents/lab work/preeti_repos/preeti_repo/MSST_2015/economic-model/src/test3.py", line 20, in <module>
                t.pool()
              File "/Users/preetigupta25/Documents/lab work/preeti_repos/preeti_repo/MSST_2015/economic-model/src/test3.py", line 15, in pool
                result = pool.map(self.run(), range(10)) 
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
                return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
                raise self._value
            TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
            [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Should that be `pool.map(self.run, range(10))`?

Comment: that gave error related to pickling. 'PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed'

Comment: This may help but it looks complicated. http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1076491?page=last

Comment: self.run() yes should be `self.run`. It doesn't accept parameters but you give it one (`range`). Also, I also had this Dict error in my code. I managed to only give a string as parameter instead of a dict, and it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

**The function signature:**

```
 def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
```

**This is an example for you:**

```
# coding=utf8
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(x):
    return x * x


def run(self):
    y = {'write_bandwidth': 3768.3135113756257}
    return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(run, range(3)))
```

And the result:

```
[{'write_bandwidth': 3768.3135113756257}, {'write_bandwidth': 3768.3135113756257}, {'write_bandwidth': 3768.3135113756257}]
```

**If you dont understand yet, please click** 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction

Good Luck!